# Python 3 Error Missunderstanding (IndexError)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code

```
def abc(l,z):
    L=[]
    länge= len(L)
    for x in range(0, länge+1):
        L[x]+z
        print(L)

abc(["1","2","3"],"-")
```

I want the program to output "1-2-3"

l in `abc(l,z)` should be a List out of Strings which combines `"l"` and `"z"` to a single String.

I'm getting an `Index Error: list index out of range`.

Comment: You want to use `str.join()` instead; `'-'.join(["1","2","3"])` does what you want *already*.

Comment: Why did you use length + 1 for the range? Python indices are zero-based, there is `len(L)` index, the last index is at `len(L) - 1`.

Comment: Note that `L[x]+z` produces a new result that you then *ignore*. It is dropped. `L` is not altered.

Comment: The question seem very basic. You should try some things on your own before throwing questions here.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here.

First, `range(0, länge+1)` will stop at `länge` but your list only has indexes from `0` to
`länge - 1`, so that's one source for an `IndexError`.

Second, `L[x]+z` will give you another `IndexError` because `L` is empty but you try to access `L[0]` (and in the next iteration, where you don't get because of the error, `L[1]`, `L[2]`, and so on).

Third, even without an `IndexError` the statement `L[x]+z` will do nothing. You compute the value of `L[x]+z` but then you don't assign any variable to it, so it is immediately lost.

Fourth, in order to `print` your final result, put the call to `print` after the `for` loop, not inside. Consider using `return` instead of `print` if you actually want to do something with the result the function produces (make sure to educate yourself on the difference between `print` and `return`).

Fifth, you want to build a string, so the usage of the list `L` does not make much sense. Start with an empty string and add the current item from `l` and `z` to it in the loop body (coupled with a re-assignment in order to not lose the freshly computed value).

Lastly, there's no point in using `range` here. You can iterate over values in a list direclty by simply writing `for x in l:`.

That should give you enough to work with and fix your code for now.

(If you don't care why your function does not work and this is not an exercise, simply use `str.join` as suggested in the comments.)